# How to call a powershell script with arguments in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, powershell, command-line-arguments

I want to call a powershell script with arguments from nodejs. I have tried the below but not working.

```
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

    let comd = '"C:\\Cmdlets\\StartSessionPasswordShown.ps1 "arg1" "arg2" 35107 "arg4"';
    child = spawn("powershell.exe", [comd]);
    child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
        let res = data;
        console.log("Powershell Data: " + res);
    });
    child.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
    });
    child.on("exit", function () {
        console.log("Powershell Script finished");
    });
    child.stdin.end();
```

And I am getting below error

Unexpected token 'arg1' in expression or statement.
The string is missing the terminator: ".

Powershell Errors:     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: `"C:\\Cmdlets\\StartSessionPasswordShown.ps1` is missing a closing `"`

Comment: that was a typo mistake while putting it here, m getting the same error with that

Comment: Unexpected token 'argx' in expression or statement.

getting above error with every argument passed

Comment: So as to avoid a distraction, please fix typos in your question after they have been pointed out to you.